# How to Async a Dynamically Created Silverlght ComboBox in the Entity Framework

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework-4

I have created a silvlerlight application That has a Tab Control on a page. When the user clicks on the last tab(the tab farthest to the right on the tab control) the application dynamically creates a grid with two comboBoxes in the grid on the newly created tabtemplate. I need to be able to populate the comboBox with data. I am also using the Entity Framework.

So I have the Entity Framework Async code for populating the comboBox:

---

Private WithEvents client As New PresListServiceClient

```
Public Sub GetPresentationList()
    client.GetInspectionListAsync()

End Sub


Private Sub client_GetInspectionLisatCompleted(sender As Object, e As InspecListServiceReference.GetInspectionListCompletedEventArgs) Handles client.GetInspectionListCompleted
    Dim results = e.Result

    acc.ItemsSource = results
    client.CloseAsync()
End Sub
```

---

The comboBox is named acc

But the problem I have is that I am dynamically creating the ComboBox "acc" when the user clicks on the last tab. I know what the name of the comboBox is going to be but because it does not exist before runtime I can't write:

```
acc.ItemsSource = results
```

I get the error *acc is not declared*

How can I do this?

Please help

Thank you
.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got some `Grid` within wich you create Combobox - then you could do:
`ComboBox acc = myGrid.FindName("acc") as ComboBox ;`

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple casting like this :

```
ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
cb.ItemsSource = results;
```

If you bind your method to your ComboBox i think it will work.

Comment: i did it in C# because i dont know how to do in VB , hope you get it.